# Visual Studio Code Entity Framework Core Add-Migration not recognized

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, command-line, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I've used yoman to generate an ASP.Net Core Web API application via the Visual Studio Code Editor. For reference, I followed this tutorial [here](https://raygun.com/blog/2016/10/net-core-docker-container/).

The API works fine. However, I am trying to use EntityFramework Core Migrations with SQL Server. When I type the following into the Visual Studio Code Terminal:

```
Add-Migration MyDbInitialMigration
```

I get the following message:

> 'Add-Migration' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools: 1.1.0-preview4-final` dependency installed. I did this using the .Net Core Project Manager (Nuget) extension.

In Visual Studio 2015 this command works fine from the Package Manager Console.

I assume that using Visual Studio Code's Terminal is the problem. But does anyone know how I can use EF Core Migrations from within the VSCode editor itself?

**Solution**

Running the `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate` command yielded the following error:

> No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"

To solve this I needed to install the following dependency, And add it to the tools section:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet
```

Comment: To further your suspicions, can you confirm the same doesn't work in a console? Please also post your full `project.json` or packages file.

Comment: from console you should use the following: dotnet ef migrations add MyDbInitialMigration. I think the same should be in VS terminal.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The correct format to add a new migration is:

```
dotnet ef migrations add yourMigrationName
```

and to update database is:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

Comment: Thank you - found the official documentation that explained this based on your answer.

Comment: Hope you're still around to see this comment... I'm having trouble finding the official docs on the new way to do this with the dotnet CLI. I actually came to this StackOverflow page after Add-Migration didn't work. Mind sharing where you found this in the docs?

Comment: For those who want to check the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db?tabs=visual-studio

Comment: But for solutions with many projects, how to specify one project to make add migration or update database on it?

Comment: From Terminal window, cd into the project root folder before running the command. A new Migrations folder will appear in that project folder with all the migration artifacts as expected.
Here is an updated link to MS docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet

Comment: I found I had to use `dotnet-ef` that is with the hyphen.

Comment: Before running the above command make sure that you have selected the correct project folder and valid ConnectionStrings with "Encrypt=False" and proper db credentials

Answer (score 30):

You need to add:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

Answer (score 3):

Im working on Mac, so Ruby is installed by default. My EF commands required lots of extra parameters `--project`, `--startup-project` etc. This was a pain to type every time, so I used rake to make this easier.

In my project root, I added a file called `rakefile` with these contents:

```
desc "Add Migraion"
task :'add-migration' do
    ARGV.each { |a| task a.to_sym do ; end }  
    puts ARGV[1]
    sh "dotnet ef migrations add " + ARGV[1] + " --project MyProject.Data/MyProject.Data.csproj --startup-project MyProject.Web/MyProject.Web.csproj "
end

desc "Remove Migraion"
task :'remove-migration' do
    ARGV.each { |a| task a.to_sym do ; end }  
    puts ARGV[1]
    sh "dotnet ef migrations remove --project MyProject.Data/MyProject.Data.csproj --startup-project MyProject.Web/MyProject.Web.csproj"
end

desc "Update Database"
task :'update-database' do
    ARGV.each { |a| task a.to_sym do ; end }  
    puts ARGV[1]
    sh "dotnet ef database update --project MyProject.Data/MyProject.Data.csproj --startup-project MyProject.Web/MyProject.Web.csproj"
end
```

Then at the command line, I run these commands:

```
rake add-migration <migrationName>
rake remove-migration
rake update-database
```

Answer (score 2):

1. First we need to add reference in `*.csproj` file in the following way

   ```xml
   <ItemGroup>
       <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.2" />  
   </ItemGroup>
   ```
2. in Bash/Command prompt

   ```
   dotnet restore
   ```
3. after that

   ```
   dotnet ef migrations add MyDbInitialMigration
   ```

Comment: Add reference in .csproj file for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet

Comment: You can use the edit link under your post to make an update.

Answer (score 0):

If any one trying to create Migrations from cmd and facing issues like this.

first try to run:

> dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version=(specify)

then try adding migration:

> dotnet ef migrations add DbInitialMigration

then update the database:

> dotnet ef database update