# EF Core migration error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Earlier, add migrations was not working for me since the migration and dbcontext were in different assemblies. After I move both of them inside the same assembly, that error doesn't occur anymore, instead, I am getting this new error.

Since there is not much information other than the stack trace, I am unable to find where the problem is.

Command:

```
dotnet-ef migrations add identity
```

Stack trace:

> System.NullReferenceException:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.CSharpHelper.Literal(String
>   value)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator.Generate(CreateTableOperation
>   operation, IndentedStringBuilder builder)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator.Generate(String
>   builderName, IReadOnlyList1 operations, IndentedStringBuilder builder)
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationsGenerator.GenerateMigration(String
>   migrationNamespace, String migrationName, IReadOnlyList1 upOperations,
>   IReadOnlyList1 downOperations)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String
>   migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String
>   language)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String
>   name, String outputDir, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String
>   name, String outputDir, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_01.b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
>   action) Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Please let me know if I need to post more code and please specify what code I should post.

Comment: as long as you will get error to add migration through the dotnet-ef migrations add then use this commend Add-Migration identity and  after use this commend Update-Database in your Package Manager Console.

Comment: I am doing the migration from VS Code.

Comment: please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41536800

Comment: Which version of EF are you using?

Comment: @MuhammadHannan I am using EF Core 3.0.0.

Comment: Does any of your entity configuration has `HasComment`? If yes, remove it and try again.

Comment: @MuhammadHannan Yes. It does. Commenting it out solved the issue. Please add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/17909) with EF core which causes `System.NullReferenceException` when you `Add-Migration`.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The reason issue occurs is when any of your entity configurations have `HasComment` in it. It's fixed and will be available via EF core 3.1 Nuget (currently is in preview). For EF core 3.0 the workaround is to remove any `HasComment`.

Answer (score 0):

Please **Remove** **HasComment** from DbContext